# Graphics problems with AMD Athlon 3000G and MSI B450M

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, amd-processor, amdgpu-pro

I'm new to Ubuntu.  I just bought a new PC for my son and we want to dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

The PC has an Athlon 3000G with a MSI B450 and a m.2 SSD.

When I log in to Ubuntu, there is a problem with the desktop.  I also can't seem to get amdgpu-pro from AMD's page, so I'm a bit lost.

It is almost impossible to navigate on the Ubuntu desktop due to the graphics issue.

I have also tried change the screen resolution with `xrandr -s 800x600` but this did not solve the problem, and might have made it worse:  The native resolution for the screen is 1440x900.

[image]

Comment: is there a dedicated GPU (graphics card) or is the only display adapter your Athlon 3000G?

Comment: Only display adapter on athlon 3000g

Comment: Did you check for the latest firmware updates for your B450?  Even new usually needs updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer prevents the amdgpu driver to load  .
On my  Lenovo Ideapad L340-17API , it freeze desktop   after a few minutes.
Correct answer is from [Failed to put a second screen Xubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243884/failed-to-put-a-second-screen-xubuntu-20-04) and [ArchWiki: Ryzen](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ryzen)

- Edit again `grub.conf` to remove previously added  "nomodeset" parameter, then run `sudo update-grub`
- Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xx-amdgpu.conf`
- Add the line `Option "TearFree"  "true"`    just before the last line:

```
Section "Device"  
     Identifier "AMD"    
     Driver "amdgpu"  
     Option "TearFree"  "true"  
EndSection
```

Save and reboot.

Comment: Thanks again, lauego you had been very helpful, it really was a matter about amdgu already installed. It's nice that people on Ubnuntu care about others. "TearFree" really solved the problem so I can now get the 1440x900 native resolution on that pc. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem with Xubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad L340-17API, which have AMD gpu.

You need to set "nomodeset" parameter at boot , as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/):
    Edit    /etc/default/grub :
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Add "nomodeset" to line  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT . This line becomes  :
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`
Save by hitting Ctrl+O, then exit nano with Ctrl+X, then  run:
   `sudo update-grub`
Reboot

*(Not related,    but the desktop  had random freeze , so i had to revert to Xubuntu 18.04 . The amdgpu driver is installed but not loaded in 20.04, I guess its the problem  )*

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much, that really worked for my problem. Now I can log in on Ubuntu and work on it. Actually resolution it's only 1024x768 and don't display other modes, but there is a big data to search on these. Ubuntu It's a really a great comunity. Kudos 