# 18.04 - Failing to shutdown/power off on AMD Ryzen CPUs

Tags: 18.04, kernel, shutdown, reboot

When booting up Ubuntu 18.04 with a kernel version of 5.3.0-52 or later (including 5.3.0-53), everything seems to be working as usual. However, when I shutdown, the system will only soft shutdown, with the CPU still running at full power, forcing me to hold down the power button to fully power off affected systems. If I reboot, it will cause the system to hang and not respond. Either way, a hard reset or poweroff will be required, and this is not an option for systems being remotely accessed. It is not possible for me to collect kernel logs at this point, unless something wrong is happening in those kernel versions before the actual shutdown.

It is possible that this may also occur on Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel versions 5.4.0-29 and later, but I have not yet tested this out. This problem is occurring on both my desktop and laptop computers which respectively are:

- AsRock B450 Pro4 with AMD Ryzen 3 3200G APU
- Lenovo ThinkPad A485 with AMD Ryzen 5 Pro 2500U mobile APU

In the meantime, I am stuck on kernel version 5.3.0-51, as that is the last working 5.3.x kernel version offered in the standard Ubuntu repositories that doesn't have this problem, without me having to use PPAs. I don't know if this problem also occurs on systems with Intel CPUs, as I don't own any recently-made system (last 3 years from 2017) with such CPUs to test if this problem occurs on them.

**Update: Reboots are also affected, not only shutdowns.**

Comment: Is Fast Boot, Quick Boot, or Rapid Boot enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: None of those three things I have enabled. This looks more like to be a problem in the kernel, since I haven't encountered this problem in older kernel versions.

Comment: I also have this problem when using Asus TUF Gaming (AMD Ryzen 7), the current solution is boot into advance mode on grub section and select kernel **5.3.0-51-generic**

Comment: I filed a related bug report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe/+bug/1880041

Comment: I'm affected by this as well, Acer Aspire 5 (AMD Ryzen 5 3500U) on (X)ubuntu 18.04 with Kernel 5.3.0-53-generic.

Comment: Same problem with Lenovo Ideapad L340 Ryzen 7, Ubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: Hi, just want to share this. lastly I got update from Ubuntu. Turns out the Linux Kernel was upgraded to **5.3.0-59-generic** and the problem has gone.

Comment: Same good result as @AdityaKresnaPermana reports when upgrading to 5.3.0-59-generic. Lenovo Ideapad L340 Ryzen 7 3700U, Ubuntu 18.04.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the brand new T495 AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 3700U. I manage to solve it on 5.3.0-53 by installing AMD drivers from here https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-10

The 5.3.0-51-generic didn't work for me from the beginning (it hangs on the login screen - I'm using unity instead of gnome)

Hope it helps

Comment: Same problem with Lenovo Ideapad L340 Ryzen 7, Ubuntu 18.04.4
How do I install the AMD drivers suggested? Sorry, I'm not so good at computers.

Comment: You'd need to download the archive, unpack it and then run the script inside it (there is a README file there with the instruction which script you should use)

Answer (score 0):

- I had this "power off" problem on a  Lenovo Ideapad L340-17API using Xubuntu 18.4.
- It was solved by using Xubuntu 20.04 but then, the display was  broken :
  Adding "Option "TearFree"  "true" in amdgpu.conf  solved :
  See answer [Graphics problems with AMD Athlon 3000G and MSI B450M](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241888/graphics-problems-with-amd-athlon-3000g-and-msi-b450m/1243985#1243985)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.