# Failed to put a second screen Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, screen, gpu-driver

I just installed Xubuntu 20.04 LTS. It is a clean installation. At the moment of connecting my second screen and then to place it as an extended screen the following happens.

**Notebook**
[image: Notebook]

**Second Screen**
[image: scree]

Please help.

**Update**

I found the solution in the next link [Screen-tearing Fix](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ryzen)

Edit the next file in

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xx-amdgpu.conf

Or

> /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xx-amdgpu.conf

And add the next line

```
Option "TearFree" "true"
```

Remaining as follow

```
Section "Device"
     Identifier "AMD"
     Driver "amdgpu"
     Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: Just wondering if it's a hardware thing because it looks like something your GPU is doing, had you used a second screen with this laptop before? Press the super key and put in "drivers" for a link to look for available drivers... are there any more drivers available for your system?

Comment: @Rabbit Yes, i used before in Xubuntu 18.04 and works fine. I fixed it using this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ryzen [Screen-tearing (APU)]. Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant! If you want you can post an answer to your own question summarizing exactly what you did and also sharing the link to the wiki (because links on their own might not last forever )